# Negative Lookahead for whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the [online regex tester](http://regex101.com/) to test my regular expressions.

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will match a URL (meaning it has to start with `http://`. Don't worry about `http://s` because I have an array that checks for each individually. `http://` won't be hardcoded into the expression. It'll be a variable string.

So this is the regular expression I have so far:

```
/http:\/\/.+(?!\s+)/g
```

It's supposed to match `http://`, then any character after that until it hits whitespace.

For example (the grey is what should be matched):

`http://example.com/foo` is my favourite website and `http://192.168.0.1` is my gateway IP.

However, the entire string is matched with that regex.

The negative lookahead, `(?!\s+)`, is what I think I should be concerned with. I'm expecting it to match until it meets whitespace. If I use this negative lookahead: `(?!$)`, it will match everything except for the last character at the end of the line, as expected.

Why does `(?!$)` work as expected, but not `(?!\s+)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting to match until whitespace, use `\S` which means any non-white space character.

```
~http://\S+~
```

**Note**: If using PHP, you can use a different delimiter to avoid escaping. And `g` is not a valid modifier in [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org)

Comment: No `g`? The website uses it and it works. Oh well. This works and I get it.

Comment: +1 for compact and easier on the eyes thanks to the new delimiter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Positive Lookahead-  Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `non-greedy` way.

```
http:\/\/.+?(?=\s)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jM9tL1/3)

Comment: But this matches the entire string just like mine does. If you use my example, it matches the words after the URL as well.